# How to test a class initialization in after_save callback with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, callback, initialization

I have the following method:

```
class Topic
def create_or_rename_folder
  unless self.destroyed?
    bucket = CreateTopicFolder.new(bucket_name)
    bucket.create_or_rename_folder(permalink.split("/").last)
  end
end
...
```

which is called like: `after_save :create_or_rename_folder, :if => :production_env?`

I would like to test that upon creating a new `Topic` a new `CreateTopicFolder` instance gets created, and *also* that if a `Topic` is being destroyed, a new instance of `CreateTopicFolder` is *not* being created.

That class looks something like:

```
class CreateTopicFolder

   def initialize(bucket_name)
    s3 = AutoVideoAssociate
    s3.connect
    @bucket = s3.find_bucket(bucket_name)
  end
  ...
```

What is the right way to go about testing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context "When creating a Topic" do
  it "creates a CreateTopicFolder" do
    create_topic_folder = mock(CreateTopicFolder)
    CreateTopicFolder.stub(:new) { create_topic_folder }
    create_topic_folder.
      should_receive(:create_or_rename_folder).
      with("Sample Bucket Name")
    topic = Topic.new
    topic.bucket_name = "Sample Bucket Name"
    topic.save!
  end
end

context "When destroying a Topic" do
  it "does not create a CreateTopicFolder" do
    CreateTopicFolder.should_not_receive(:new)
    topic = mock_model(Topic)
    topic.destroy
  end
end
```